# Connectedness of sets acting on topological groups...

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I come now with a topological group question.
Suppose a topological group $G$ acts on a topological space $X$. Suppose $G$ and $X/G$ are connected. Show $X$ is connected. 
Me and a few friends have been pondering this one for awhile to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $q:X\to X/G,\ x\mapsto G\cdot x,$ is a quotient map because we equip $X/G$ with the quotient topology.

One can prove that if $q:X\to Y$ is a quotient map and $Y$, as well as all the fibers $q^{-1}(y),\ y\in Y$ are connected, then $X$ is connected, too, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302059/how-to-prove-this-result-involving-the-quotient-maps-and-connectedness/302081#302081).

In your case the fibers $q^{-1}(G\cdot x)$ are just the orbits $G\cdot x$. Since $m:G\times X\to X,\ (g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x$ is continuous, we see that $G\cdot x=m(G\times\{x\})$ is connected, being the continuous image of a space homeomorphic to $G$.

Comment: I have proven the lemma about the pre-images of fibers already. I do not know how to show that the inverse image of a coset is connected, however.

Comment: @AnthonyVasaturo: $q^{-1}(Gx)=Gx$. Can you show that $Gx$ is connected using the fact that $G$ is connected? Use that $G\times X\to X$ is continuous.

Comment: I don't exactly see why this map is open nor do I see why G connected means coset Gx is connected. I tried by contradiction, and the only thing I could say was that if A and B formed a separation for Gx, then G was entirely contained in A or B.

Comment: @AnthonyVasaturo: Whoops, sorry, I realize that you do not need openness of that map, and openness is proven using the map is a quotient map, lol.

Comment: So the image of G x {x} must be connected since that is isomorphic to G, and X is a union of all such images, all of which intersect at a common point, making X connected?

Comment: Also, not every quotient map is open!

Comment: @AnthonyVasaturo: I know. But the proof that $q$ is open makes use of the fact that it is a quotient map. If $U$ is open, one shows that $q^{-1}(q(U))$ is open.

Comment: So, then it is open because every open set in X is simply an inverse image of an open set in X/G. I see.

Comment: By the way, where can I learn the script that let's you type all those fancy looking letters?

Comment: @AnthonyVasaturo: No, not every open set $U$ is inverse image, but its saturation $q^{-1}(q(U))$ is open.

Comment: But U must be equal to the inverse of q(U) for that to be a saturation, correct?

Comment: @AnthonyVasaturo: $q(U)$ is open iff its inverse $q^{-1}(q(U))$ is open, by definition of quotient map. This $q^{-1}q(U))$ is called the saturation of $U$. OK, I will tell you, this set is equal $GU$ which is open. Can you see why?

Comment: @AnthonyVasaturo: Take a look here for the fancy looking letters: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. If you see the *edit* link under a post, you can click it to see the source code of that post.

Comment: H: the set GU is open as the inverse image of U in the second map you posted. Correct?

Comment: @Anthony: $GU=\{gu\mid g\in G,u\in U\}$ is the union $$\bigcup_{g\in G}gU$$. Since $x\mapsto gx$ is a homeomorphism, each $gU$ is open, so is the union $GU$. But this set is just $q^{-1}(qU))$.