# Is this proof correct: domain of a quotient map $p:X\rightarrow Y$ is connected when $p^{-1}(y)$ is connected for each $y\in Y$ and $Y$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-verification

The domain $X$ of a quotient map $p:X\rightarrow Y$ is connected when $p^{-1}(y)$ is connected for each $y\in Y$ and $Y$ is connected.  Proof:

If $X = F \uplus G$ for two nonempty closed sets $F,G$ in $X$.  Then $F$ can be partitioned into connected components as well as $G$ such that no connected component touches both $F$ and $G$, otherwise there would be a separation of the component and it wouldn't be connected.  Then $p(F)\cap p(G) = \{\}$ or else $p^{-1}(y)$ for $y$ in the intersection would be contained in a connected component touching both $F$ and $G$.  This can't happen.  Then $p^{-1}(p(F)) = F$ and similarly for $G$, so $p(F)$ and $p(G)$ form a separation of $Y$ which can't happen since $Y$ is connected, so $X$ must be connected.  Right?!

Thanks.

Comment: It seems right to me. I think you're saying it a bit too complicatedly though. $p(F)$ and $p(G)$ are disjoint, else you'd disconnect a fiber, and for the same reason $p^{-1}(p(F))=F$ and $p^{-1}(p(G))=G$, so that $p(G)$ and $p(F)$ are closed. Thus, $p(F)\cup p(G)$ is a disconnection of $Y$.

Comment: What I wrote was my simpler answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prove this result involving the quotient maps and connectedness?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302059/how-to-prove-this-result-involving-the-quotient-maps-and-connectedness)